# Creating a URL link with href not going to the URL

Tags: javascript, url, attachments, angularjs

We have a page that is using AngularJS.  I am creating a link:

```
<div ng-if="breakout.AttachmentFiles">
    <div ng-repeat="file in breakout.AttachmentFiles" style="display: flex; align-items:baseline;">
        <b style="width: 95px; text-align: right">Attachments:</b>
        <a href="file.Url">{{file.Url}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

File structure is:

```
  else if (itemKey === "AttachmentFiles") {
    var foobar = [];

    angular.forEach(itemValue.results, function(value, key) {
      foobar.push({"Url": $location.$$host+value.ServerRelativeUrl+"", "FileName": value.FileName});
    });


    console.log("AttachmentFiles | foobar: ", foobar);

    currentBreakout[itemKey] = foobar;
  }
```

[image]

For the text of the href displays the correct url, but the link it self goes off to a /Pages/file.Url:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I changed

```
<a href="file.Url">{{file.Url}}</a>
```

to

```
<a href={{file.Url}}>{{file.Url}}</a>
```

and that gives me a new link:

[image]

So for some reason `https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Pages/` is being inserted before the actual URL.

Solved:

With the help from Ganash's post about using `{{}}` instead of `""` and adding `http://` to the url, the link is now working correctly.

Comment: After it creates a link, inspect the anchor element and check if it creates a link correctly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<a href="{{file.Url}}">{{file.Url}</a>
```

Or

```
<a ng-href="file.Url">{{file.Url}}</a>
```

Comment: The `{{}}` got me the actual URL in it now, but for some reason the `https://companyName.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/pages` is being inserted before the URL I want.

Comment: Then you must be creating wrong url after fetching the attachments and adding in foobar.

Comment: I agree.  I don't know where.  This is AngularJS which I am not not familiar with at all.

Comment: I needed to include `http://` in the url, now it is working as intended.